# Incorrect syntax return when execute in store procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am still new on store procedure.

Could anyone help and tell me what is wrong with this ?

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateProductionReport]

@whereClause nvarchar(max)

As
Begin
    declare @id int, @itemNum nvarchar(20), @datetimestamp datetime, @tStations_id int
    declare @counter int, @itemNumPrev nvarchar(20)
    set @counter = 0
    set @itemNumPrev =''
    set @whereClause = ''
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    create table #Temp
    (
    id int, 
    itemNum nvarchar(20),
        tStations_id int,
       datetimestamp datetime,
       groupID int



    )


    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  

    select id,itemNo,tstations_id,datetimestamp
    from
    tProduction_Count  @whereClause
    --where datetimestamp between '2017-03-16 00:00:00' and '2017-03-16 23:59:59'
    ORDER BY id ASC 

    OPEN db_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id, @itemNum,@tStations_id, @datetimestamp
```

The error I got is :
**'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spCreateProductionReport, Line 42
Incorrect syntax near '@whereClause'.'**

Comment: Is the @whereClause variable a parameter or did you forget to `declare` it?

Comment: it should be a parameter, I will be use the whereClause to get the string/text from the front end and use it as filter here

Answer (score 2):

You can't just mix the parameter in the query you are writing.

You'd need to use dynamic SQL to do this, in that way you'd be building the whole query as an string.

Like:

```
EXEC('select id,itemNo,tstations_id, datetimestamp from tProduction_Count ' + @whereClause)
```

However, you cannot declare a cursor over that dynamic query, so one way would be to insert the results of that execution into a temporary table and then build the cursor over that table.

If you could avoid dynamic SQL altogether by receiving parameters that you use in a regular query, that'd be better as dynamic SQL can be harder to debug and also if you are receiving this from the front end you can be exposed to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `DECLARE` the variable first

`DECLARE @whereClause nvarchar(max)`

Also, this doesn't look right: `select id,itemNo,tstations_id,datetimestamp from tProduction_Count  @whereClause`

What is the `whereClause` variable doing here?

Comment: I have declare the @whereClause before the AS Begin

Comment: We can't tell where Line 42 is. See edit, I added another point

Comment: I would like to use the whereClause as a filter, which I will be getting and passed from front end. is there any better way?

Comment: Line 42 is actually the line of 'select id,itemNo,tstations_id,datetimestamp from tProduction_Count  @whereClause'